# Convert Activity To Fragment: Black Screen and Restart

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments

I am converting an application that uses Activities to use Fragment instead. I changed the xml of one view to have a FrameLayout where I will place the Fragments. The issue I get is when I attempt to set the Fragment, the screen goes black and "Application terminated." gets outputted to the console and the application reboots.

You will find my code snippets for the MainActivity, the main XML, the Fragment. Any hints on why this is happening would be really appreciated.

Activity

```
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        //Start the fragment
        Fragment gameManager = new GameManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment_container,gameManager)
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dip" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></FrameLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/start"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/start" >
        </Button>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/options"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" >
        </TextView>

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/option_max_points"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:prompt="@string/option_max_points" >
        </Spinner>

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/mixed_trade"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/option_mixed_trade" >
        </CheckBox>

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/auto_discard"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/option_auto_discard" >
        </CheckBox>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/player_red"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" >
        </TextView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/name1"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:text="" >
            </EditText>

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/human1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/human" >
            </CheckBox>
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/player_blue"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" >
        </TextView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/name2"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:text="" >
            </EditText>

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/human2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/human" >
            </CheckBox>
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="@string/player_green"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" >
        </TextView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/name3"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:text="" >
            </EditText>

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/human3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/human" >
            </CheckBox>
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/player_orange"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" >
        </TextView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/name4"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:text="" >
            </EditText>

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/human4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/human" >
            </CheckBox>
        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/reset"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/players_reset" >
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Fragment

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    fa = (FragmentActivity) super.getActivity();

    CatAndroidApp app = (CatAndroidApp) getActivity().getApplicationContext();

    RelativeLayout frame = new RelativeLayout(getActivity());

    TextureManager texture = app.getTextureManagerInstance();

    if (texture == null) {
        texture = new TextureManager(getActivity().getResources());
        app.setTextureManagerInstance(texture);
    }

    //changed constructor
    view = new GameView(this,getActivity());
    renderer = new GameRenderer(view);
    view.setRenderer(renderer);
    view.requestFocus();
    view.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1));
    frame.addView(view);

    boolean horizontal = getActivity().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels < getActivity().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
    resources = new ResourceView(getActivity());
    resources.setOrientation(horizontal ? LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL : LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params;
    if (horizontal)
        params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    else
        params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    params.addRule(horizontal ? RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM : RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    frame.addView(resources, params);

    board = app.getBoardInstance();


    turnHandler = new UpdateHandler();

    //return frame;
    return frame;
}
```

Comment: post your error log

Comment: @TruongHieu Thanks for your comment. Literally the only thing that gets printed to console is "Application terminated"

Comment: Are you sure you checked the "logcat" tab as well as console?  If yes, put some debugging statements so you can see where it gets to -- does onCreateView even get called?